# How to setup ArangoDB replication via the ArangoDB Go driver

Tags: go, arangodb

I need to set up a simple replication schema with a secondary database. I figured out that using `arangosh` I can set it up with the following commands:

```
db._useDatabase("myDB");
require("@arangodb/replication").setupReplication({
  endpoint: "tcp://main-server:8529",
  username: "user",
  password: "pass",
  verbose: false,
  includeSystem: false,
  incremental: true,
  autoResync: false,
  autoStart: true,
  restrictType: "include",
  restrictCollections: [ "Products" ]
});
```

This setup, however does not seem to persist. Connection going down, or server restarts make it disappear.

So, I would like to set up some monitoring and re-establishment of the replication in my  Go program.

I searched both the ArangoDB website Manual pages, and Go driver documentation but I could not find anything that would allow me to run the above setup in Go using the driver.

Additionally, I didn't find how I could interface with `arangosh`, and possibly run the JS code above and get the results. Is that possible somehow using the Go driver?

Comment: I never did this myself in a professional capacity, but AFAIR such setups are supposed to use the arangod starter: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/tutorials-starter.html

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a solution to this.

The Golang driver does not provide this functionality. But Arango has a pretty simple HTTP based API which allows access to all functions and features of the database engine.

Here's the link to the documentation I used: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/http/index.html
(I'm using version 3.8 because after that the type of replication I needed was no longer part of the community edition).

Setting up a replication requires just two steps:

- PUT request to the /_db/*yourDBname*/_api/replication/applier-config with a JSON payload:

```
{
    "endpoint":"tcp://serverIP:8529",
    "database":"yourDBname",
    "username":"root",
    "password":"password",
    "autoResync": true,
    "autostart":true
}
```

- And another PUT request to get the replication actually started, to /_db/*yourDBname*/_api/replication/applier-start . This one doesn't need any payload
- And to see how things are going you can do a GET request to /_db/*yourDBname*/_api/replication/applier-state

All these requests need a JWT token that you can get with a POST request to /_open/auth  with a payload of:

```
{
  "username": "user",
  "password": "passwd"
}
```

The token you receive will need to be included in the HTTP header as a bearer token. Pretty simple.